# Unsure of Rank / Dense_Rank - Mulitple Columns - change rank when unique combination changes

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, order-by, uniqueidentifier, rank

I need to get the unique combinations of 2 fields, with a RankID for each unique combination

In this example I need to create new IDs for each Customer/Value combination.

```
Source table:

CustID     Value
1   20.00
1   50.00
1   50.00
2   30.00
2   50.00
2   50.00
```

Should return this please ( change when either of the columns change)

```
Nr  CustID     Value
1   1   20.00
2   1   50.00
2   1   50.00
3   2   30.00
4   2   50.00
4   2   50.00
```

Thus there are 4 unique combinations of Customer/Value
and thus 4 nrs.

SQL:

```
declare @table table(
CustomerID int,
Value       decimal(18,2)
)


insert Into @table(CustomerID,Value)values(2,50)
insert Into @table(CustomerID,Value)values(1,50)
insert Into @table(CustomerID,Value)values(1,50)
insert Into @table(CustomerID,Value)values(2,50)
insert Into @table(CustomerID,Value)values(1,20)
insert Into @table(CustomerID,Value)values(2,30)

select * from @table


select  RANK()   OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID,Value ORDER BY  Value  DESC) as Rank ,
* from @table
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e60e/3

Comment: perfect thanks, all the examples had something in the Partition By section which I should have left out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID, Value)
```

Test at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e60e/5)**